# What does "Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse." mean in Actions on Google

Tags: php, json, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am trying to get a simple webhook (written in PHP) to work with dialogflow/actions on google.  I have a dialog flow intent labled "hello" which is linked to the "google assistant welcome" and dialog flow "welcome" events.

it is set to enable webhook, and everything works correctly in the dialog flow test area.  when i test it in google assistant, however, i get the following error:

"MalformedResponse
Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse."

I have no clue what is wrong.  Here is what my JSON response looks like:

```
{
  "payload": {
    "google": {
      "expectUserResponse": false,
      "richResponse": {
        "items": {
          "simpleResponse": {
            "textToSpeech": "test speech"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "fulfillmentText": "fulfillment test"
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It works in the Dialogflow test area because that just tests the Dialogflow portion of the response. It ignores anything under the platform-specific `payload` area.

Your payload contains a small error. The `items` property of the [`richResponse`](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppResponse#richresponse) should be an array of [item](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppResponse#Item) objects, even if you're only sending one.

So that part of your JSON should look more like:

```
  "richResponse": {
    "items": [
      {
        "simpleResponse": {
          "textToSpeech": "test speech"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```